# Why is creating and using an Expression faster than direct access?

Tags: c#, .net-core, benchmarking, expression-trees

I am currently implementing some dynamic filtering/sorting and thought it was a good idea to do a benchmark to see how things are looking.

First, here's the method creating an expression acting as a "getter":

```cs
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> GetPropertyGetter(string propertyName, bool useCache = false)
{
    if (useCache && _propertyGetters.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        return _propertyGetters[propertyName];

    var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
    var property = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (property == null)
        throw new Exception($"Property {propertyName} was not found in entity {entityType.Name}");

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
    var convertedProp = Expression.Convert(prop, typeof(object));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(convertedProp, param);

    if (useCache)
    {
        _propertyGetters.Add(propertyName, expr);
    }

    return expr;
}
```

Here's the benchmark:

```cs
public class OrderBy
{

    private readonly List<Entry> _entries;

    public OrderBy()
    {
        _entries = new List<Entry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++)
        {
            _entries.Add(new Entry($"Title {i}", i));
        }
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public List<Entry> SearchTitle()
    {
        return _entries.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(p => p.Title).ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<Entry> SearchTitleDynamicallyWithoutCache()
    {
        var expr = DynamicExpressions<Entry>.GetPropertyGetter("Title");
        return _entries.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(expr).ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<Entry> SearchTitleDynamicallyWithCache()
    {
        var expr = DynamicExpressions<Entry>.GetPropertyGetter("Title", useCache: true);
        return _entries.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(expr).ToList();
    }

}

public class Entry
{

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public Entry(string title, int number)
    {
        Title = title;
        Number = number;
    }

}
```

And here are the results:
[image]

So my question is, why does creating an expression (which uses Reflection to get the property) faster than a direct access (`p => p.Title`)?

Comment: Technically, those are _all_ expressions.  You would have to look at the expression tree generated for each of them to see what's different about the one that is automatically generated for you by the compiler.

Comment: Look at the generated IL or paste in sharplab. It will show you all the Expressions created by the compiler for your lambda. Then compare that to what you've got manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `GetPropertyGetter` method generates a lambda that converts the result of the property into an `object`. When `OrderBy` sorts by `object` instead of by `string`, the comparison used is different. If you change the lambda to `p => (object)p.Title` you will discover it is faster as well. If you change the `OrderByDescending` to take a `StringComparer.InvariantCulture`, you will see a slight speed up over your generated lambdas.

Of course, that also means your dynamic `OrderBy` most likely doesn't handle other languages properly.

Unfortunately once you start to dynamically create code like the lambda for a LINQ method, you can't always just substitute `object` and expect the same results (e.g. an `int` field will be boxed, `string` won't use the same comparer, types with custom comparers may not work, ...). Basically I think of `Expression` building for dynamic type handling as like the GPL - it spreads out (and up) like a virus. If you replaced `OrderByDescending(GetPropertyGetter)` with dynamic `OrderByPropertyNameDescending(string)` and built the call to `OrderBy` as well, you would get what you expect.

Consider:

```
public static class DynanmicExt {
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> OrderByDescending<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> q, string propertyName) {
        var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
        var property = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (property == null)
            throw new Exception($"Property {propertyName} was not found in entity {entityType.Name}");

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity,string>>(prop, param);

        var OrderBymi = typeof(Queryable).GetGenericMethod("OrderByDescending", new[] { typeof(IQueryable<TEntity>), typeof(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>) })
                                         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity), prop.Member.GetMemberType());
        var obParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<TEntity>));
        var obBody = Expression.Call(null, OrderBymi, obParam, expr);
        var obLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>>(obBody, obParam).Compile();

        return obLambda(q);
    }
}
```

Oh, almost forgot it needs these handy Reflection helpers:

```
public static class MemberInfoExt {
    public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.FieldType;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.PropertyType;
            case EventInfo mei:
                return mei.EventHandlerType;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}

public static class TypeExt {
    public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(this Type t, string methodName, params Type[] pt) =>
        t.GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.Name == methodName && mi.IsGenericMethod && mi.GetParameters().Select(mip => mip.ParameterType.IfGetGenericTypeDefinition()).SequenceEqual(pt.Select(p => p.IfGetGenericTypeDefinition()))).Single();
    public static Type IfGetGenericTypeDefinition(this Type aType) => aType.IsGenericType ? aType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : aType;
}
```

Now you can use it with:

```
public List<Entry> SearchTitle2() =>
    _entries.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending("Title").ToList();
```

This is now just as slow as the lambda is to run.

Comment: Indeed, using `(object)p.Title` does make the comparaison more close between the two. I'm wondering why do you think of generated Expressions as a virus, if you of course have the time to elaborate. In the meantime, I'm marking this as an answer.

Comment: @Haytam I updated my answer to include the code to build `OrderBy` at runtime. Not sure how to explain virus better - consider, you decide to runtime create the lambda for `OrderBy`, but you can't use it in a static type compile time environment, so then you must create the code to call `OrderBy` at runtime. Fortunately the return type from `OrderBy` is statically typed, or the virus would spread to its callers, etc. e.g. if you had started by runtime creating the lambda for `Select`...